# multiprocessing.Process.start() raises exception django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

#### Views.py

```
def time_consuming_task_caller(time_to_sleep, j):
    print ('start', task_id)
    # time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
    # print('finished', task_id)


def time_consuming_task_caller(time_to_sleep, j):
    Process(target=time_consuming_task, args=(time_to_sleep, task_id)).start()
    print ('processing...', task_id)
    return {'one': 'two'}


def get_task(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        response = time_consuming_task_caller(5,1) # 5 is like time to sleep, 1 is task id.
        print(response)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
```

This causes error at `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")` because it prints all three print statements (except the commented one)

Even with `time.sleep()` commented it causes the error. Ultimate goal is to make it work for processes that may take longer to execute.

### EDIT

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', get_task ,name='run')
]
```

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\webapp - Dev\server 3\manager\utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .models import Task
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\webapp - Dev\server 3\manager\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from accounts.models import CustomUser
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\webapp - Dev\server 3\accounts\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\env_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\env_django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\env_django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\env_django\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "D:\Programming\django_project\env_django\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Can you also show an example `urls.py`? And what is the error?

Comment: Your code will be more clear if you use descrpitive names in place of `i` and `j`. Do you really want to wait for the return value of `time_consuming _task_caller()` before returning an `HTTPResponse`? If so, what is the point of multiprocessing here? You can get the same results with synchronous code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - updated i, j and added stack trace. Also I don't want to wait for it to return the value, that's why I'm using  `Process.start()`.

Comment: It causes the new process to run asynchronously, right?

Comment: It looks like the error is thrown by the "time consuming task". Does it import your models.py?

Comment: This function doesn't use anything from my models at the time of error, but later in future might have to use models directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

from the stack trace you provided the error might also be caused by your `models` file (which you didn't include).

But the right way to implement such functionality is to use a task runner like 
[celery](http://www.celeryproject.org)

Comment: I decided to use celery